# how to pose string value as a variable name to set another variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have string which contains variable name. I want to set variable reference to another variable.

for e.g.

```
var abc = 'ABCValue'; // variable
var str = 'abc'; // string which is having variable name

function set(variableName){ // variableName = 'abc';
  var newVar = variableName.replace(/["']/g, ""); // var newVar should have value of abc variable which is 'ABCValue'
}
```

I tried replacing single and double quotes from the string to make that value to pose as a variable but it's not working out for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not use `new` as a variable name

Comment: why you don't make variables as `array["var_name"]=value`

Comment: array is not possible as I am setting this variables from other services.